# Need to check if Item is null

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, nullable

How can I check if this item has a value

```
int? b = null

if (/*b has a value*/)
    //Do Work
```

My friend says to try this and it works but it seems convoluted

```
return (new List<int?>() { b }).Any(a => a != null);
```

Comment: You comment `if (/*b has a value*/)` but you haven't tried `if(b.HasValue)` ?

Comment: Your friend is a troll

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `HasValue`

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets a value indicating whether the current Nullable object has a valid value of its underlying type.

so try:

```
if (b.HasValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nullable supports both == and != operators, and they also have the HasValue attribute, which is true whenever they actually hold a value (are not null).

```
if(b != null)
{
// do stuff
}
```

or

```
if(b.HasValue)
{
//do stuff
}
```

work just the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
int? b = null;
if(b.HasValue)
{
    // do your work
}
```

Have a look at this: [Nullable Types (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

> Use the HasValue and Value read-only properties to test for null and retrieve the value, as shown in the following example: `if(x.HasValue) j = x.Value;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if(b != null)
{
}
```

or

```
if(b.HasValue)
{
}
```

Your existing code is effectively using the first, albeit in a very convoluted manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
return b==null?0:b;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(b!=null)
{
    var c = b.Value; //Where c will be of type int
}
```

You can directly use

```
var c = b.GetValueOrDefault(32); //Where 32 will be given, if b is null
```

Comment: That second part of your response does not have much to do with the OP's question.